# Determing class path for jar html embed

Tags: java, html, jar, classpath, embed

I'm trying to serve an a JAR executable as a web app. I'm having issues figuring out the class path for the "code" attribute. The JAR was originally packaged on a CD-ROM.

Double clicking on the JAR itself (BDH.jar) executes `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe"  -jar "C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\My Documents\3. Current Projects\BDH\BDH.jar"`

Double clicking on the bundled .exe executes "Differential Equations.exe" `"C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\My Documents\3. Current Projects\BDH\jre\bin\javaw.exe" -Xms134217728 -Xmx268435456 -classpath "C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\My Documents\3. Current Projects\BDH\BDH.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\My Documents\3. Current Projects\BDH\lax.jar;" com.zerog.lax.LAX "C:/Documents and Settings/xxxx/My Documents/3. Current Projects/BDH/Differential Equations.lax" "C:/Documents and Settings/xxxx/Local Settings/Temp/lax29DC.tmp"`

Both of these launch the app successfully.

Oh, I'm using "applet-fu.js" to try and load this. I found a bunch of likely classes inside BDH.jar and have tried loading them without luck:

```
applet_fu.run(
  {'width':'550','height':'320'},
  {
    'archive':'BDH.jar',
    'code':'com/artmedialab/main/BDH.class'
  },
  '1.4.2',
  '<p>Please install Java.</p>'
);
```

Any hope of making this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a double-clickable app, turns out I can't use it as an applet (not without changes, anyway). Apparently the way to distribute desktop apps over the web is by using JavaWebStart (sometimes called JNLP). See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html for more details.